# How could I get Dom Element in *ngIf with angular 4

Tags: angular

In my page, I have 4 steps using `*ngIf` to switch between each `div`, just like

```
<div *ngIf="step===1"></div>
<div *ngIf="step===2"></div>
<div *ngIf="step===3"></div>
<div *ngIf="step===4"></div>
```

And I have a `canvas` element in step 2 to render using data from step 1.
My problem was, when user click the *next step* button, I change `step = 2`, and I need to render `canvas`. But as we know, the `canvas` element won't exist until angular rendered UI.

So is there a way to get the `canvas` element after angular rendering?

Though I know `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` could do this, but is there a `*ngIf` way? `setTimeout` was not in my concern.

Comment: canvas is dynamically loaded or it is just hidden?

Comment: @wannadream just hidden

Comment: then you can use javascript to manipulate it,

Comment: I'm not quite getting it. Could you please explain in more details?

Comment: someone gave you a detail now. take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this works, but worth a try:

```
 <div *ngIf="...">
   <canvas #canvas>
```

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

@ViewChild('cd') canvas:ElementRef;

step = 1;
nextStep() {
  this.step++;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  console.log(this.canvas.nativeElement);
}
```